# Bash getopts doesn't show error for second option

Tags: bash, getopts

I want a script to take in two options, both are required. if I pass one in, the script doesn't print an error requesting you to pass in a second one.

```
-bash-4.2$ bash test.sh -b
Invalid option: b requires an argument

-bash-4.2$ bash test.sh -p
Invalid option: p requires an argument

-bash-4.2$ bash test.sh -b sdfsfd

-bash-4.2$ bash test.sh -p sdfsfd

-bash-4.2$ bash test.sh -b sdfsfd -s sfd
Invalid option: s
```

## Code

```
showHelp()
{
cat << EOF

Find files in client's folder and upload to S3 bucket.

Usage: $(basename $0) [-p PATH_TO_SEARCH] [-b S3 bucket]

OPTIONS:
  -h    Show this help message
  -p    Path to search
  -b    S3 Bucket

EOF
exit 1
}

while getopts ":p:b:h" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        h)
           showHelp
           ;;
        p)
            p=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        b)
            b=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        \? )
            echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG";;
         : )
            echo "Invalid option: ${OPTARG} requires an argument";;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${p}" ]; then
   showHelp
fi

if [ -z "${b}" ]; then
   showHelp
fi
```

Comment: Add a counter in the each case statement or a flag, check they are correct after the case statement.

Comment: Working fine on `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`, which version of `bash` do you have?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I can't tell (from what you've posted), if the variables `b` and `p` have been previously set (either in this script or prior to calling the script); what I typically do is ... just before the `while getops...`, I make sure my option variables are undefined, eg: `unset b p while getopts ...` so that post-getopts testing of the option variables works as expected

Comment: @markp they are not previously set.

Comment: Options are, by definition, optional. `getopts` is not requiring that *either* `-b` or `-p` be used, let alone both (nor can it be made to do so). Rather, `getopts` can only ensure that *if* `-b` or `-p` is used, then an argument is given to the option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure you get *both* options, you can use something like:

```
no_p=1
no_b=1

while getopts ":p:b:h" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        h)
           showHelp
           ;;
        p)
            p=${OPTARG}
            no_p=0
            ;;
        b)
            b=${OPTARG}
            no_b=0
            ;;
        \? )
            echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG";;
         : )
            echo "Invalid option: ${OPTARG} requires an argument";;
    esac
done

[[ $no_p -eq 1 ]] && echo "No -p provided" && exit 1
[[ $no_b -eq 1 ]] && echo "No -b provided" && exit 1
```